# NameError in Pygame - global name "name" is not defined

Tags: python, class, pygame

I'm writing up a simple game in Pygame, but I've come across a bothersome error. I've grouped a bunch of code related to drawing the movement vectors in two separate functions, one for each image.

```
from __future__ import division
import math
import sys
import pygame


class MyGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def cat_chase():
        # bunch of code here

    def dog_chase():    
        # more code

    def run(self):
        # event handling           

    def draw(self):
        """Update the display"""
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)

        self.cat_chase()
        self.dog_chase()


        pygame.display.flip()

MyGame().run()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Then, the error I get is:

```
    NameError: global name 'cat_chase' is not defined
```

I'm wondering why cat_chase is not defined? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you reload this file after adding `self.` to the start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `self` argument to your methods:

```
def cat_chase(self):
    ...

def dog_chase(self):
    ...
```

So you can call it as:

```
obj.cat_chase()
```

Comment: While this is true, it cannot be the source of the named exception, as it would provoque other types of error. But it needs to be fixed as well in order to make the stuff work, so +1 nevertheless.